# Help me decide my business name

Tags: business, freelance

I've been freelancing as a graphic designer for some time now marketing myself with my real name and it's been bugging me for quite some time now. I really want to change that.

The issue is not that I can't find a word combo to use for myself. With enough research I'd find something eventually. The issue is I would really like to use my ages old nickname, Bubily. It's what my friends and people online know me as. It's a stupid little nickname I got completely randomly years ago, it stuck and I love it. The sound of it and even the look of the word fits my personality and all that. I'm just worried it's not suitable for my business because it's obviously not a real word (not that I know of at least) and it doens't asociate with the actual work I do and all that.

Right now I'm working "only" as a graphic designer. Branding, print work, digital art, all kinds of stuff but eventually I'll also get heavily invested in game design so having a weird, quirky name like that could seem usefull I guess.. maybe?

Any way, what do you guys think of "Bubily" or "Bubily Design Studio" or something along those lines?

Comment: Know the feeling, 'Bubily Design' sounds pretty good. It could make for a cool logo.

Comment: How do you pronounce bubily?

Comment: Forgot to mention that. It should be pronounced boob-e-lee, although most english speaking people think it's bubbly, which is fine by me I guess

Comment: I voted to close this as primarily opinion based due to the fact this is asking if something sounds good or not

Comment: If it's not about whether or not it sounds good and rather about whether to use a personal name or something else, it'd be a duplicate of [this question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/58722/23061)

Comment: Don't be too afraid to have a quirky name. My business goes by 'Bakabaka Design', which is Japanese for 'idiots!'.

Comment: @Zach Saucier I asked if the name is suitable at all for a design business. The nature of the word itself and I was hoping to get some info about made up words, nicknames and what not being used for design businesses and such. Is it acceptable to use something like this or should I keep looking for something better defined or obvious.

I'm sorry if this wasn't the place for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me 'Bubily' sounds so good :) Sounds unique too! Personally I feel deciding the business name is a huge task and it gives lot of happiness and satisfaction when we finally decides the official name for our business.

BTW, my business name is "[The Digital Vibes](http://www.thedigitalvibes.com/)" :)